virtualbox hides itself after a time
I've been living with it because it was more trouble than it was worth to fix, but I thought I would see if anyone has a quick answer for me.
I have an Ubuntu 24.01 (but this has been happening for many versions) which is the host for a Windows 11 PC supported by VirtualBox 7.0 (7.0.22r165102). I have 7 virtual workspaces, but that number has ranged from 4 to 10 in the past and all have exhibited the same issue. I have the most recent vbox extras added and the PC is running in seamless mode.
When I leave the guest alone for a while, the window is minimised into the dock. If I click on the dock icon, it opens fine. Why does it minimise into the dock after a while? How do I make it stop doing that?
Thanks

Silly question, but how likely is it that you might have pressed [Ctrl]+[Super]+[D] or Ctrl+Alt+D? This keyboard shortcut will minimise all windows, and the [D] key is pretty close to other common keys that require [Ctrl]+[Super] or [Ctrl]+[Alt]

That's a really good thought, but alas, I'm certain I haven't touched any keys while focused on VirtualBox instances. I do use ++ to navigate my workspaces. As an experiment, I navigated back and forth past them and they didn't minimise.

My Virtualbox, currently on 24.04 running a Windows 10 VM guest, has never minimized unexpectedly, nor done anything else unexpected. It's been reliable for years.

that's a good data point. in general, vbox has been my friend. it's a minor thing, but it's just been annoying. i wonder, do you run your vbox in seamless mode?
